how to add event to FullCalendar Component without calling api
im currently trying to add events to my object instead of adding the event via getApi().addEvent(...).
Ive tried it by simply adding a new event to the array but instad of 2 events the old one got deleted. Currently im Using Angular with Primeng.
this is my Calendar variable.
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent!: FullCalendarComponent;
events = new Subject<any[]>();

in case of a new selected time im calling the function
  handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
    this.showDialog();

    if(!this.activeDialog){
      let newEvent = {event:data};

      this.calendarComponent.getApi().addEvent(newEvent);
      this.calendarComponent.getApi().unselect();
    }
  }

instead i want to add it to a Subject<any[]> (named events).
if i replace this.calendarComponent.getApi().addEvent(newEvent); with   this.selectedRoom.tmpEvents.next([newEvent]);. Instead of multiple events getting shown, the old events get deleted and only the new one is shown.

Why do you want to avoid using the API? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. That's how you're supposed to use the calendar, as documented. Anything else is not really guaranteed or supported.
